How to resolve build failure due to core-location dependency in Android project with Gradle?
I'm experiencing a build failure when running ./gradlew clean build on my Android project. The error message indicates a problem with the core-location dependency from androidx.core. Here are the details:
Calculating task graph as no cached configuration is available for tasks: clean build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Configuration cache state could not be cached: field `compileTimeDependencies` of task `:app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsRelease` of type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.databinding.DataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsTask`: error writing value of type 'org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.ResolutionBackedFileCollection'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.core:core-location:1.13.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve androidx.core:core-location:1.13.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/androidx/core/core-location/1.13.0/core-location-1.13.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/androidx/core/core-location/1.13.0/core-location-1.13.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Configuration cache entry discarded due to serialization error.

It appears that the build process is attempting to download the core-location dependency from api.mapbox.com, but it is receiving a 403 Forbidden response. I am not sure why it is trying to fetch this dependency from Mapbox or how to resolve this issue.
I have tried the following without success:
Cleaning the project and rebuilding.
Running the build with --stacktrace, --info, and --debug options for more insights.
Any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Is there a configuration I need to change, or is there an issue with the repository access?
Context:
Gradle version: 8.7,
Android Gradle Plugin version: 8.5.0
Thank you!

I do not see that Google actually has an artifact with those coordinates. So, while part of your problem feels like you removed google() as a source of dependencies, I do not know that adding it back will fix the problem.
